# Cheap and easy solution for VPN?

Tags: vpn

I would like to access my office-network from remote via VPN.

My router is a Zyxel Prestige 600, and from what I have been able to google, does not support VPN in itself.

What would be a cheap and easy way to set up VPN?

Comment: So, did dd-wrt work out for you?

Comment: I changed location shortly after, where I did not control the router - so I had to drop the idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could re-flash your router firmware with a version of **dd-wrt** that contains **openvpn**

Configuration can be a bit tricky, but once it's done, it's done - and there are some pretty good howtos out there on doing this.

Comment: I've done this successfully on several Linksys-WRT54GL and it's working great. I even use this solution to provide possibility to work remote for a small company (<10 employees).

Comment: OpenVPN is great. If you can embed it in a cheap router it's perfect. Forget about over-over-over-priced cisco.

Comment: +1 very good point, saves on needing to setup a seperate VPN server

Answer (score 5):

If your router does not support VPN, then you will need a VPN server running inside your network and port forwarding on your router. The most common servers include the VPN server built into Windows (RRAS) or OpenVPN.

Comment: OR - if you can flash the firmware with something like dd-wrt or openwrt, you may be able to add VPN support to the router.

Answer (score 1):

I just picked up a Cisco PIX 501 router on eBay for $95 and plan to use it for VPN purposes.  From what I've heard online and from my friends that deal with Cisco stuff, it's a pretty solid solution for my VPN needs.

Answer (score 0):

My two would be either just properly SSL-protecting all the services you need, which, if it's just mail and web, can be really easy, or another vote for OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Astaro Security Gateway](http://www.astaro.com/our_products/astaro_security_gateway).

It has an easily implemented SSL VPN (OpenVPN), and the added bonus much stronger security! It can be purchased as a hardware appliance (< $1000) or as software (< $500) and installed on generic hardware.  I *believe* the software is available free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty happy with Linksys RVL (RVL-200 ) and RV (RV-082 or RVL-042) series.Pretty good, not expensive, works like a charm. I connect to my client's Asterisk servers regularly with no problems.